# FSM. Filter must be callable and/or awaitable!

Tags: aiogram-2.x

Применил FSM, aiogram 2*. Получаю такую ошибку: TypeError: Filter must be callable and/or awaitable!

Все вроде бы делал по инструкции [FSM](https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-2-guide/fsm/). Понимаю что ошибка типа. Но может в 2 версии aiogram пишется как то иначе? не могу найти в документации. Заранее спасибо!

```
class UserStates(StatesGroup):
    find_group = State()

@dp.message_handler(text=['Найти группу'])
async def func(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    await message.answer("Введите номер группы", reply_markup=keyboard)
    state.set_state(UserStates.find_group)

@dp.message_handler(UserStates.find_group)
async def func(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if(message.text == '7'):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели номер группы 7")
    elif(message.text == '6'):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели номер группы 6")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такой группы не существует")
    state.clear()
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:\Users\******\Desktop\pythonProjectuchenik\pythonProjectuchenik\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\pythonProjectuchenik\pythonProjectuchenik\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    async def func(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 560, in decorator
    self.register_message_handler(callback, *custom_filters,
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 486, in register_message_handler
    self.message_handlers.register(self._wrap_async_task(callback, run_task), filters_set)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 62, in register
    filters = get_filters_spec(self.dispatcher, filters)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\filters.py", line 48, in get_filters_spec
    data.append(get_filter_spec(dispatcher, i))
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\filters.py", line 28, in get_filter_spec
    raise TypeError('Filter must be callable and/or awaitable!')
TypeError: Filter must be callable and/or awaitable!

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопросе. Чтобы было понятно хотя бы - на какую именно строку он ругается.

Comment: Благодарю, что поправили вопрос. В следующий раз буду более понятно изъясняться :)

Comment: Так, начнём с того, что нельзя делать несколько методов с одинаковым названием. Давайте методам понятные и **разные** имена. В Питоне не важно сколько и каких аргументов у функции, если название совпадает, то **последующие объявления функций маскируют предыдущие**. Впрочем, у вас и аргументы совпадают, но не важно. Поэтому у вас нет двух функций `func`, у вас есть только одна - последняя.

Comment: Ну и пометьте, какая строка вашего кода на самом деле 25-я, потому что код не весь и так и непонятно, на какую строку он ругается.

Comment: И обработка команд там вроде по-другому описана: `@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="отмена", ignore_case=True), state="*")`, мне кажется как у вас `@dp.message_handler(text=['Найти группу'])` - это неправильно.

Comment: 25 строка: async def funcq(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

Методы я переименовал.. А вот на счет обработки команд не совсем понятно, есть ли документация? В документации FSM об этом не пишут.

Comment: Как это не пишут, я открывал именно приведённую вами ссылку )  А приведённая вами строка в вопросе присутствует **два раза**. Какая из двух этих строк 25-я - решительно непонятно.

Comment: ааа. ошибку он указывает на @dp.message_handler(UserStates.find_group) и после функция где выставлены условия if.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по приведённой вами же ссылке, вот эта строка написана неправильно:

```py
state.set_state(UserStates.find_group)
```

Она должна выглядеть так (исправления в двух местах):

```py
await state.set_state(UserStates.find_group.state)
^^^^^^                                     ^^^^^^
```

Видимо, состояние устанавливается неправильно и поэтому обработчик сообщения, обращаясь к этому состоянию, ругается.

Ну и, кроме того, как я уже писал в комментарии, у вас одинаковые названия функций `func`, вторая перекрывает первую. Именно поэтому лучше использовать "говорящие" имена функций, так меньше шансов, что они совпадут. В данном случае это могли бы быть такие названия функций: `input_group` (происходит ввод названия группы) и `find_group` (собственно сам поиск группы по названию).